# App killed onBackPressed android

Tags: android, back-button

I start a Service from an activity that gets messages from service and shows in a Dialog. When I click back or Home button, app is killed. And app is not found in the multitasking area. I didn't write any code on onBackPressed(). How may I rectify this issue? Service Code.

```
public class BleepService extends Service{
String gotAlert;
Context context;
String drAlert=null;
public static boolean status = false;

public static final String TAG = BleepService.class.getSimpleName();
int counter = 0;    
static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
private Timer timer = new Timer();
String resServer;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("SERVICE", "COMES TO THE ON STARTCOMMAND");   
    doRepeat();     
    //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY; 
}

private void doRepeat() {
    Log.i("SERVICE", "COMES TO THE DOREPEAT METHOD");
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() { 

    new GetStatus().execute();      

    }
    }, 1000, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
}

class GetStatus extends  AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {           
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        resServer = sh.makeServiceCall(Urllist.urlGetPagerStatus, ServiceHandler.GET);
        while(resServer.equals("1"))
        {
        status = true;
        resServer = sh.makeServiceCall(Urllist.urlGetMsg, ServiceHandler.GET);              
        }
        return resServer;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Log.i("SERVICE", "COMES TO THE GetStatus AsyncTask Class");
        super.onPostExecute(result);        
        if(!result.equals("0"))
        {       

            Intent i = new Intent("com.bleep.DR_ALERT_MESSAGE");
            i.putExtra("msg", result);
            sendBroadcast(i);

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No New Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }       
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //timer.cancel();
    //super.onDestroy();
    /*if (timer != null){
        timer.cancel();
    }*/
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `Service` returns `START_STICKY` in its `onStartCommand`. This way OS will restart it if it ever gets killed.

It is legal for an app to be killed by the Android any time while the app is in the background.

However, OS very rarely kills `Services`. Are you sure you do not somehow kill it yourself, maybe, due to some bug?

Comment: OS will kill the app when there is memory issue, but in this case I don't get any clue from Logcat window

Comment: Are you sure you are starting your service at all?

Comment: yes starting service in OnCreate(). now I've replicated app, & found out the issue. Polling server continuously for response, at once I get the response, send it to the BCR which opens a Dialog with yes and No buttons. Before I respond to the Dialog it launches one more Dialog as the Time Delay is 5000ms. How may I fix this? please refer above code. Thanks.

Comment: You could use Dialog.isShowing() to check if you already have a Dialog